# difference between curandState_t and curandState

Tags: random, struct, cuda, typedef

In the cuRAND documentation, both types curandState_t and curandState are used. Are there any difference between them?

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#device-api-overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same. In `curand_kernel.h` you will find this:

```
typedef struct curandStateXORWOW curandState_t;
typedef struct curandStateXORWOW curandState;
```

i.e. both types are aliases of the state for the default XORWOW generator state type.